# Parallelizing a finite difference computation using cython and prange

Tags: python, c, openmp, cython

I wish to calculate the residual error of a 2-dimensional Poisson equation elliptic solver in parallel using Cython. However, it seems that naively using `prange` seems to slow down my code instead of speeding it up. I am using the following code snippet for the parallel computation

```
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef double[:,:] GetRes2(double[:,:] u, double[:,:] f, double h):
    cdef:
        int i, j
        int N = u.shape[0]
        double h2 = h*h
        double[:,:] res = np.zeros([N,N], dtype=DTYPE)
        
    with nogil, parallel(num_threads = 2):
        for i in prange(1,N-1, schedule='static'):
            for j in range(1,N-1):
                res[i,j] = f[i,j] - (u[i-1,j] + u[i+1,j] + u[i,j-1] + u[i,j+1] \
                    - 4*u[i,j])/h2
    return res
```

In fact, there are other parts of the code which I wish to parallelize with a similar slow-down effect compared to my serial code, but I think solving this problem is representative of the other problems which I need fixing.

I am using the following `setup.py` to compile the cython code

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(
    name='Methods',
    ext_modules=cythonize(Extension("methods", ["methods.pyx"],
            extra_compile_args=['-openmp'],
            extra_link_args=['-openmp'],
            include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
            ))
)
```

I am also reading Chapter 12 of Kurt W. Smith's Cython book, which covers parallelization, and he cites a similar calculation as an example of the pitfalls of parallization. He explains that "part of the reason is that the loop body primarily accesses noncontiguous array elements."

I have also implemented a version of the code with contiguous memory views, to no avail. Unfortunately, Kurt W. Smith did not provide a solution how one could parallelize such a calculation.

I thought that since each element of the array `res` is a calculation independent of other calculations, this counts as an "embarassingly parallel computation". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How big is `N` in your case? How big is the slow-down? Can you provide the timings?

Comment: Running it within my larger project, where only `GetRes2` can either run in parallel or not, the serial code gives a `totime` of 0.105 s while the parallel code gives a `tottime` of 0.127 s. This is for `N` = 641.

Comment: Ok. With `N` = 641, the loops in `GetRes2` should run in less than 1 ms, so I guess you are measuring the time of `GetRes2` put in a time loop, isn't it?

Comment: Ahh, I'm running it as part of a code that calls `GetRes2` multiple times. However, I think I get what you're trying to say now. The parallelization should start outperforming the serial code only at larger `N` since the compiled serial code is optimized and finishes in less than 1 ms for `N` = 641.

I've made `GetRes2` callable from python and, sure enough, when I fed it 5121x5121 matrices, the parallel code now runs faster with approximately 2x speed up I was expecting when running on two threads.

Thank you!